# Error with back slash in python open statement

Tags: python, string, windows, syntax-error, filepath

Is there any way without typing `r` or 'double slash' to resolve this problem.because this two tricks change the type of file:

```
f = open('C:\Users\alireza\Desktop\exersices.python\p5.files\1.txt')
```

Error:

```
File "<ipython-input-1-243f8d6a931c>", line 1
    f = open('C:\Users\alireza\Desktop\exersices.python\p5.files\1.txt')
            ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Comment: Can you please indent your code properly: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and please ask your question not only in the title, this might also be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: You can use `/` forward slash to refer to the path of the file in windows.

Comment: I don't think using `r'...'` literals or double backslashes would change the type of the file in any way. What makes you think it does?

Comment: Why is this question tagged "unicode", I don't see anything outside ASCII? It does not take any knowledge about unicode to see that the substring `"sers\ali"` in not a valid hexadecimal number.

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your issue.

```
f = open('C:/Users/alireza/Desktop/exersices.python/p5.files/1.txt')
```

Comment: Note that if long-path support (i.e. more than 260 characters) is required via the `"\\\\?\\"` prefix, the path must be unicode (e.g. a `u""` literal in Python 2) and use backslash as the path separator. Also if it's passed as a command-line argument, a path should use backslash since many programs blindly interpret forward slash as an option/switch.  You can normalize forward slashes to backslashes via `os.path.normpath`.